# Multiple Select2 items - shared LOV

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, jquery-select2-4

So, I’m leveraging the famous Select2 plugin (3.0.3) on apex 4.2. I’ve got 3 Select2 items all sharing the same list of values.

The list of values is bumped up against a fairly large employee table; about .5 million records. I’m not returning .5 mil, but instead taking a subset of about 200,000 records..

Here’s the problem.. each of these items take 2 seconds to load the very same LOV. Therefore, I’m looking at 6+ seconds to load the page.

Is there anyway for me to load the LOV just one time instead of three?

Interestingly enough if I add a “read-only” condition on these items the page loads instantaneously. I find this interesting, because Select2 does not support a read only condition. Obviously I cannot keep this condition in place.. just sharing some additional info that may help find a solution.

Thanks!!

[Select2 plugin](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=64237:20:0:)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you should use lazy loading for such big lists. Go to the settings of Select2 and mark the property `Lazy Loading`. After that, put `100` (for example) in `Lazy-append Row Count` property. After that all lists should load instantly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I’m indeed already using lazy loading w/ 20 in the lazy-append row count. It still takes 2 seconds per the 3 Select2 items.

Comment: @hisnameismyname2 This is strange. I think you need to investigate the reason, probably, fetching the first 20 rows also takes a lot of time.

Comment: What are you saying is strange? The fact that each Select2 item is taking 2 seconds despite sharing the same LOV? More info: the debug log clearly shows the 2 second duration when the LOV is processed.

Comment: additionally, while not a comparison of Apples to apples.. I can fetch 50 rows from sql developer in less than half a second.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @hisnameismyname2 Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Gili nope, I had to cut my loses and move on.

Comment: @hisnameismyname2 I ended up doing the same. I ended up using https://github.com/yairEO/tagify/